# Why is my bash executed python script outputting just the filename to a txt file?

Tags: python, bash, command-line-arguments

I have two files.
A bash that executes a python file. For now, I'm just trying to understand how command line arguments work for python by simply printing the command line argument.

I want the command line argument to be the "i" in the bash loop...

```
do
    /usr/bin/time python3 file_name.py $i > ./run/file_output$i.txt
done
```

The python file

```
import sys

def run():
     print(sys.argv[0])

if __name__ == "__main__":
     run()
```

The output txt files are created and numbered correctly, but each one just has filen_ame.py instead of the value of i.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `sys.argv[0]` is the executable name, not the first parameter, as you'll see from the following program:

```py
import sys
for arg in sys.argv:
    print(arg)
```

When running it, you'll see:

```
pax> python3 prog.py a b c
prog.py
a
b
c
```

In other words, if you want the first argument, use `sys.argv[1]`.